# How to store results of loop If statement in another worksheet columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to store the results of my for each If statement in the results worksheet of  the active workbook.

My loop works but I need to be able to store the results in column a and c from the results worksheet

This is the code for the loop

```
  For Each cel In Range("A4:A85")

            With cel

               If (.Value Like "boston*" Or .Value Like "manfield*" Or _
            .Value Like "barnes*" Or.Value Like "langley*") _
            And .Offset(0, 2).Value Like "mass*" Then



                 MsgBox cel.Value & Chr(13) & Chr(10) &  cel.Offset(0, 
2).Value
```

I was thinking about something like this

```
 Pseudocode: worksheets worksheetname column.value = cel.value and 
cell.offset(0,2).value =cell.offset(0,2).value
```

Comment: What happened when you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
Sub Michael()
    Dim v As String, WhichRow As Long
    Dim cel As Range
    WhichRow = 1

    For Each cel In Range("A4:A85")
        v = cel.Value
        If (v Like "boston*" Or v Like "manfield*" Or v Like "barnes*" Or v Like "langley*") And cel.Offset(0, 2).Value Like "mass*" Then
            MsgBox cel.Value & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & cel.Offset(0, 2).Value
            Sheets("results").Cells(WhichRow, "A").Value = cel.Value & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & cel.Offset(0, 2).Value
            WhichRow = WhichRow + 1
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```